# What is the simplest way to check if a procedure's parameters are all NULL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Lets say I have a stored procedure like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE People_Select
    @LastName   nvarchar(25)    = NULL,
    @FirstName  nvarchar(25)    = NULL,
AS
BEGIN 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM People
    WHERE (@LastName IS NULL OR (LastName = @LastName))
      AND (@FirstName IS NULL OR (FirstName = @FirstName))

    OPTION (RECOMPILE)

END
```

When this gets executed and at least one (or both) of the parameters are set it works perfectly. However, if someone happens to call it without setting either parameter it will return all rows from the People table. This is problematic especially if my People table has millions of records.

The preferred functionality (in my case) would be for it to return nothing if NO paramters are set. I could easily check if lastName is null AND if firstname is null and return nothing but is there a more elegant way of doing this? What if my stored procedure had 20 optional parameters? I don't want to check if they are ALL null first and return nothing.. is there an easier way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE People_Select
    @LastName   nvarchar(25)    = NULL,
    @FirstName  nvarchar(25)    = NULL,
AS
BEGIN 

    IF @LastName is null and @FirstName is null
        goto end_section:

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM People
    WHERE (@LastName IS NULL OR (LastName = @LastName))
      AND (@FirstName IS NULL OR (FirstName = @FirstName))

    OPTION (RECOMPILE)
end_section:
END
```

Comment: Yes I know that will work fine. I was wondering if there is an easier more logical way to do it in the case of an sproc with 20 optional parameters. I don't want to have to check if a ISNULL AND b ISNULL AND c ISNULL..... AND z ISNULL. I'll go with this for now though.

Comment: Why goto instead of just return?

Comment: Oh and if you have lots of parameters to check, just use the coalesce function:  
`if coalesce(@LastName,@FirstName) is null return;`